# Base and Derived Class Memory Layout with void* member

Tags: c++, memory-management, polymorphism, void-pointers

I solved my own problem, but need help understanding the *why*. Client has access to Base class that they can insert their data whatever it is, `b`, that I just pass around, never use. Client will have a getter function to get their data back whenever they want. When I use "Method 1": a `Base*` to `Derived` object, I get what I want.

What I want: the client's data `b` back in its original form, which I think is guaranteed by standards if you simply cast from `SomeType*` to `void*` and then back to `SomeType*` again. When I use "Method 2": setting a `Derived*` to `Derived` object, then the client's data when they retrieve `b` does **not** come back in its original form, instead I get garbage values, so clearly not the right location in memory to the user's data.

I originally tried Method two, but figured out Method one gets me what I want. I'd like to understand why, I would have thought the `Base*` to `Derived` object would have a similar memory layout as `Derived*` to `Derived` object, just... "sliced".

Below is a contrived example to illustrate what I mean, not necessarily working code.

```cpp
struct Base { 
    int a;
    void* b;
};

class Example {
  struct Derived : public Base {
    Example* c;
  };
  Base* data1;  // Method 1: Gives me what I want
  Derived* data2;  // Method 2: Does not give me what I want

  public:
    // Method 1: Gives me what I want
    void SetData1(Base* foo) {
        data1 = new Derived;
        data1->a = foo->a;
        data1->b = foo->b;
        static_cast<Derived*>(data1)->c = this;
    }
    // Method 2: Does not give me what I want
    void SetData2(Base* foo) {
        data2 = new Derived;
        data2->a = foo->a;
        data2->b = foo->b;
        data2->c = this;
    }

    // Getter function doesn't make a difference here
    // void* GetData() {
        // return data1->b; //Method 1
        // return data2->b; //Method 2
    // }
};

int main() {
  // Example use-case
     Base* foo = new Base;
     foo->a = 2;
     SomeUserData* bar = new SomeUserData;
     foo->b = bar;
     
     Example myexample;
     // Method 1:   :)
     myexample.SetData1(foo); 
     SomeUserData* test1 = static_cast<SomeUserData>myexample.GetData();
     // Method 2:   :(
     myexample.SetData2(foo);
     SomeUserData* test2 = static_cast<SomeUserData>myexample.GetData();     
};
```

Comment: Time to read up on `virtual` functions?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. The `Base` and `Derived` structs in my example have no functions at all, it's just data.

Comment: Works just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/eeTTP3xvn Nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: Shoot okay, there must be something else causing an issue. The only meaningful difference between my example and my real code is that the `Derived` member `c` is actually of type `Example* c` , that I assign to the object pointed to by `this`.

Comment: This is what happens when you post code without verifying that it reproduces the error.